# Recovering from zmq.error.ZMQError: Address already in use

Tags: python, sockets, unix, zeromq, amqp

I hit Ctrl-C while running a `PAIR` pattern (non-blocking client servers) connection with ZMQ. Later when I tried running the `REQ-REP` (blocking client single server connection) pattern, I keep getting the `Address already in use` error. I have tried running netstat with `netstat -ltnp | grep :<my port>` but that does not list any process.

So who exactly is using this address?

Also how does one gracefully shutdown socket connections like these?

Comment: Post some code illustrating usage.

Answer (score 27):

Question 1:

If you do `sudo netstat -ltnp`, on a Linux type operating system, you will most probably see the process owning the port. Kill it with `kill -9 <pid>`.

Question 2:

When you exit the program, close your sockets and then call zmq_ctx_destroy(). This destroys the context. See http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc17 for more info.

Comment: what problems do you get?

Comment: It's been a few days and I have since resolved this, but I think `netstat -ltnp` needs additional arguments — these arguments give me the help message. I can also run it as `netstat -ltnp tcp` and that lists all TCP connections, but it doesn't show the PID. It's possible that `netstat` is different on Mac OS X than on other operating systems.

Comment: I have updated the answer with info that the answer is only valid for linux. I am sorry I do not know Mac OS X so I cannot give the correct answer on Mac OS, but after a quick search I understand the command is very different.

Comment: For others using Mac, can use this `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P` to see the PID

Answer (score 6):

### At this very moment:

```
reboot
```

### Next:

start using `try:` / `except:` / `finally:` encapsulation constructors, that will help you to **grant a graceful exit** from all zmq allocations, incl. all *Socket*-s' `.close()` and *Context*'s `.term()` without any hanging orphan(s) an memory leak(s), even in case any panic button or unhandled exception interrupts your code-execution altogether with losing references to your still hanging, network-hardware bound, instances.

Comment: This work for me, thanks. But I must do ctrl+c ( ctrl+z does not work). And it's .term(). Not .Term()

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes another zeromq-using process is keeping the port in use, and `netstat` doesn't indicate that other process listening (so `netstat -lntp` won't show it), but rather shows an established connection on the port with the same host/port on both ends.  After killing that other process, the port is now available for use.

Reason #1: I've had this happen because I had the zeromq listening ports set up in the range of ephemeral ports (on linux e.g. 32768-61000) that get used as the local side of outgoing connections, and my services need to connect to other services on the same box. A percentage of the time an outgoing connection gets an ephemeral port that is the same as a listening port on the box, and suddenly "address already in use". I just moved all the listening ports down out of the way of the ephemeral port range and all of the "address already in use" issues went away.

Reason #2: Speculation: When I've run into similar problems with other python network libraries, the offending process was previously launched from the listening process using subprocess or similar, and there was a problem with the socket leaking to the child process; if the parent process exited without closing the socket, the socket would be left alive and owned by the child process, and even though the child process didn't really know anything about the socket it would still be held up so other processes couldn't use it.

If that's the issue, it might be fixable by tweaking the flags of the socket before the subprocess, e.g. (unix-specific):

```
fd = sock.get(zmq.FD)
old_flags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFD)
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFD, old_flags | fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC)
```

Or maybe there's a way to more properly close the socket in the parent process.