# Troubles with zmq_bind() in ZeroMQ binding for MQL4 language

Tags: message, communication, zeromq, mql4

I am working on MT4 and used wrapper `mql4zmq.dll` as given in link

```
https://github.com/AustenConrad/mql4zmq
```

As I have followed all instruction and successfully loaded `DLL` as well as `lib` file at specific locations from pre-compiled. But it can not **`bind`** or **`connect`** with socket through **`zmq_connect(,)`** or **`zmq_bind(,)`**. Please some one help me to solve this problem. I am posting my code here

```
// Include the libzmq.dll abstraction wrapper.
#include <mql4zmq.mqh>

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| variable definitions                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int speaker,listener,contextt;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int init()
  {
//----
   int major[1];int minor[1];int patch[1];
   zmq_version(major,minor,patch);
   Print("Using zeromq version " + major[0] + "." + minor[0] + "." + patch[0]);

   Print(ping("Hello World"));

   Print("NOTE: to use the precompiled libraries you will need to have the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package installed. To Download: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555");

   contextt = zmq_init(1);
   speaker = zmq_socket(contextt, ZMQ_PUB);
   listener = zmq_socket(contextt, ZMQ_SUB);

   // Subscribe to the command channel (i.e. "cmd").  
   // NOTE: to subscribe to multiple channels call zmq_setsockopt multiple times.
   zmq_setsockopt(listener, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, ""); 

   if (zmq_bind(speaker,"tcp://127.0.0.1:5555") == -1) 
   {
      Print("Error binding the speaker!");
      return(-1);  
   }
```

There is problem in

```
if ( zmq_bind( speaker, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555" ) == -1 )
```

It returns **`-1`** and does not **`bind`**.

I have tried every possible thing to solve this mystery but failed.

Please let me know if I am mistaken!!!

Comment: Yes, @Junaid, Austen has made a great wrapper for MQL4 coders. Your initial experience may seem troublesome, nevertheless, ZeroMQ / MQL4 integration works excellent and brings coutless powerfull expansions to MQL4 domain. **Could you be more specific on your test setup?** What is the output **Print()**-ed into **`.log`**? What have you tried to check the true PointOfFailure? What O/S do you operate on? ( port privileges / firewall rules & exceptions apply ... ), etc. Would be great to be able get the things done. **`MQL4`/`ZMQ` is cool & so, so, so powerfull...**

Comment: I have solved this mystery and able to bind as well as connect using Austen wrapper class. Actually my port associated with IP Address was not closed properly and require free it later. Thanks for support

Comment: good to know & enjoy the powerfull worlds of ZeroMQ messaging, Junaid

Comment: @Junaid, I am facing the same problem, can you please tell me how you fixed it ? what do you mean by "port associated with IP Address was not closed properly and require free it later"

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, `address/port`-in use may block `.bind() / .connect()`

As solved in the comments above, there is 
[another post with a similar solution of the same root-cause **why the well-formed ZeroMQ-code was still not able to `.bind()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26084911/3666197)

Address/port release/re-use is O/S-dependent resource-management issue. Be carefull once developing for a production-grade operations.